# How to resolve DI issue in nest.js?

Tags: node.js, typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

I wanna understand how to import 3rd party library in nestjs through DI. So, i have a class `AuthService`:

```
export class AuthService {
   constructor(
     @Inject(constants.JWT) private jsonWebToken: any,
   ){}
  ....
}
```

JWT provider:

```
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import {Module} from '@nestjs/common';
import constants from '../../../constants';

const jwtProvider = {
  provide: constants.JWT,
  useValue: jwt,
};

@Module({
  components: [jwtProvider],
})
export class JWTProvider {}
```

Libraries module:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import {BcryptProvider} from './bcrypt/bcrypt.provider';
import {JWTProvider} from './jsonwebtoken/jwt.provider';

@Module({
  components: [
    BcryptProvider,
    JWTProvider,
  ],
  controllers: [],
  exports: [
    BcryptProvider,
    JWTProvider,
  ],
})
export class LibrariesModule{
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthService (?). Please verify whether [0] argument is available in the current context.
    at Injector.<anonymous> (D:\Learning\nest\project\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:156:23)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (D:\Learning\nest\project\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:4:58)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

Besides, I wanna hear some recommendations about not using type `any` in the `jsonWebToken` variable.

Comment: I digged a little bit deeper, and, according to comments in source code: "The component can inject dependencies through constructor. Those dependencies should belongs to the same module.". Question is the same, but how do i inject external component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The devil is in details. You can "import" other module into AuthModule like so:

```
@Module({
  modules: [LibrariesModule], // <= added this line
  components: [AuthService, JwtStrategy],
  controllers: [],
})
export class AuthModule {

}
```

Source: [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/advanced/hierarchical-injector)

Second question is still opened.

Comment: Do i need to make separate question  or keep this?